# MVC3 Custom Role Provider with many to many relationship using checkboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a customized providers in mvc3. I have a custom membership and custom provider.
I got my custom role provider work in 1 to M relatioship with my user using a dropdownlist. Now I want to have it in M to M relationship with my user using a checkbox but don't know how. I want to have the multiple selection of roles in the edit view of my user.  Any suggestions, examples and comments on this forum will be greatly appreciated . thank you in advance. :)

here's my edit in USERCONTROLLER>

```
    //
    // GET: /User/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(long id)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Single(u => u.Id == id);
        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(db.Roles, "Id", "Name", user.RoleId);
        return View(user);
    }

    //
    // POST: /User/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.Attach(user);
            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user, EntityState.Modified);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(db.Roles, "Id", "Name", user.RoleId);
        return View(user);
    }
```

my EDIT

```
        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoleId, "Role")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("RoleId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleId)
    </div>
```

my INDEX 
        
            Role Name
        
        
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Role.Name)

I'm using a repository and custom role provider to authenticate my roles... I just want to change the dropdownlist to chechboxes so that I can choose many roles for a user.. tnx.. :)

here's the link that I followed to do my custom role provider> http://www.brianlegg.com/post/2011/05/09/Implementing-your-own-RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx

Comment: Your question is a bit vague my friend. Could you please give a little more info or show some code?